# Search API returning no results even though nodes have been indexed

Tags: search

I have a very simple set up as described below.

modules:
Search API 7.x 1-1
Search Pages 7.x - 1.2
Database Search 
Devel Generate

I’ve set up a database server and an index for indexing nodes. The nodes were created using the Devel Generate module. The nodes have been indexed as shown on the Search API ->View->Index Status. On the Nodes->Index->Fields tab I’ve several options like Node ID, Content Type, Title, Status, etc. In Structure->Blocks I’ve added the Search Index to the page in the sidebar.
I also set permissions so anonymous users can administer  search.

But when administering a search nothing is returned.  For test purposes, when entering in the same search term (‘Amet’) in the default search, results are being returned.

How do I troubleshoot this? What is the problem here? Anyone help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What type have you selected for your indexed fields?
I think search_api_page only handles fields using **fulltext** indexing, and wouldn't be so useful for numeric fields like nid, or text fields indexed with the **string** type.

You could also try using Views with search_api

Comment: i checked and have the field Title type set as Full Text.